# How do I build a notification email/reply system like Facebook?

Tags: facebook, email, notifications, email-notifications

When users receive a notification email about a new private message on Facebook, they can reply to the email and have their response automatically added to the conversation on the site.

How can I build a cross platform system like that? I'm building a group chat system.

Answer (score 6):

This is obviously way over-simplified, but here we go:

The way Facebook's emails work is by using a string that's unique to the receiver in the `reply-to` address:

```
<m+50edqb50000003jtdj389k6xib6hofj6t41q1c45sdt92qc@reply.facebook.com>
```

So when Facebook receive an email into `reply.facebook.com`, they (presumably) parse the string after the plus sign, decide which user/conversation it's relevant to, and add the text of the email into that conversation.

Answer (score 4):

One option:

Send every notification email with a unique reply-to address, then receive replies with a customized SMTP server that will pair responses with the originating message object in your DB.

Since you are using django (according to your tags) I would recommend looking at the [Lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/) python SMTP server.  It can be programmed to correctly attribute each message.  Using Lamson with Django is [documented](http://lamsonproject.org/docs/hooking_into_django.html).

Comment: thanhks so much , i will try with Lamson Smtp server

Comment: @nguyen-trong-nhan How it was? Did Lamson solved your problem?