# Why is Facebook using this email format to send out email's

Tags: facebook, email

I can't seem to find any resource online that's why am asking here. If you are on Facebook and receive notification on your email when their's any activities on your Facebook Profile. If you see the email it will be written "**notification+pu5h3p_d@facebookmail.com**".

Why is Facebook using "+**pu5h3p_d**", is there any reason or anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's so if you reply to that email, Facebook's servers can identify which conversation thread it's from and automatically post your reply as a comment.

> **Here's how it works:**
>
> Facebook: [Replying to Comments through Email](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook/replying-to-comments-through-email/206480947130)
>
> Stack Overflow: [How do I build a notification email/reply system like Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405263/how-do-i-build-a-notification-email-reply-system-like-facebook)